# Robolectric custom TestRunner not working when started from Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, robolectric

I wanted to implement a custom `Application` class Shadow, to override a `getInstance()` method in it. I am using Robolectric 3.0 and have created a `MyRobolectricTestRunner` class, overriding the `createClassLoaderConfig()` method like this:

```
public class MyRobolectricTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public MyRobolectricTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    public InstrumentationConfiguration createClassLoaderConfig() {
        InstrumentationConfiguration.Builder builder = InstrumentationConfiguration.newBuilder();
        builder.addInstrumentedClass(App.class.getName());
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

The ShadowApp class looks like this:

```
@Implements(App.class)
public class ShadowApp{
    @RealObject private static App instance;

    public static void setAppInstance(App app){
        instance = app;
    }

    @Implementation
    public static App getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And the test which uses the Runner is annotated like this:

```
@RunWith(MyRobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest=Config.NONE, shadows = {ShadowApp.class}, constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class SomeShadowTest {
```

Now the problem is that when I run the test manually (hitting "Run..." for this single test class only), it passes without a problem, but when I use the Gradle "testDebug" task, the test fails as if the Shadow class was not used at all :(

I have tried changing the Runner parent class to `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`, but ended up in a dead end when it forced me to make the `ShadowApp` class extend a `ShadowApplication` class, which has getInstance() method as well... :(

Any tips on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is there anything in the logs which might help? Any errors, warnings? Did you try running with --info or --debug for a more verbose output? Also, if you try to run the entire suite from AS, instead of just this one test, does it also work fine?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not create shadow for application but instead use TestApplication class which Robolectric uses as test variant of the application class.

For this you just need to create class which extends your application class and has name Test and is placed in the root of your project - package of class same as package name of project.

See example below:

Assume, you package name is `com.example.robolectric`

```
// src/main/java/com/example/robolectric
public class YourAplication extends Application {
   ...
}
```

---

```
// src/test/java/com/example/robolectric
/**
 * Robolectric uses class with name Test<ApplicationClassName> as test variant of the application
 * class. We use test application for API class injection so we need test version of this class.
 */
public class TestYourAplication extends YourAplication {
   ...
}
```